# remote rule message in parsley.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsley.js

perhaps this is the most silly question but I really don't know how to solve this problem.

I'm using parsley.js and I did a password field validation using parsley's data-remote:

**View snippet:**

```
<form data-parsley-validate novalidate class="form-horizontal group-border-dashed" id= "form-val" role="form" action="{site_url()}admin/checkPass" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Contrase&ntilde;a Actual</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input id="actualPass" type="password" name="actualPass" data-parsley-remote="{site_url()}admin/checkPass" data-parsley-remote-options="POST" data-remote-datatype="jsonp" class="form-control" required>
    </div>   
  </div>
```

**On my admin.php:**

```
public function checkPass(){
  if (isset($_POST['actualPass'])) {
    $passMd5 = md5($_POST['actualPass']);
    $pass = ($this->data['actualUserBack']->user_password);
    if ($passMd5 == $pass) {
      echo json_encode(true);
    }else{
      echo json_encode(false);
    }
  }
 }
```

I have other fields (new password and retype new password) that works super with this parsley's validation. When you input wrong passwords then a message in red appears.

What I want to have is the same red box with a custom message in the first validation I've made. From admin.php/checkPass I'm only returning true and false in a blank page.

How do I do to use parsley validation format in that case?

Here I attach images:

What shows first checkPass function: [image 1](http://s27.postimg.org/5hupwr14j/false.png)

How I want it to look: [image 2](http://s4.postimg.org/h4z1yjc0d/pass.png)

How do I send the data? what do I have to modify or add? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have two possibilities:

- modifying your backend script to return not anymore a `true/false` result, but a `200` and `400` status code. Parsley remote validator by default acknowledge `200` response as a good validation, and all others as failures
- defining your own parsley remote validator (see custom remote validator section here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#remote) where you will check not anymore the response status **but** the response content, looking for your boolean answer.

Hope that helped.

Best